# Minikube keeps showing error for invalid flag on start

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I tried to start minikube with `--extra-config=apiserver.Features.Enable-SwaggerUI=true` flag, but for any reason it throws this error:

> ❌  Problems detected in kube-apiserver [7152cdb4684e]:
> Error: unknown flag: --Features.Enable-SwaggerUI

Then when i run the minikube again without any flags, it still gives the previous error.
Now that i don't want this feature any more, how can i run minikube without any flags being appended automatically?

Minikube v1.25.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as mentioned in [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/#kubernetes-configuration), the `--extra-config` is repeatedly being attached to `minikube start` command.
This config is stored in `[home]/.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json -> ExtraConfig key`. All i did was to remove the `Features.Enable-SwaggerUI` from this key-value.

Answer (score -1):

This command works to me
`minikube start  --extra-config=apiserver.enable-swagger-ui=true`